# How to decode an Address Resolution Packet (ARP)

Tags: networking, ip, arp

What does this ARP packet mean, or even just what bytes correspond to which fields?

```
0000   FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 C0 93 19 00 08 06 00 01
0010   08 00 06 04 00 01 00 00 C0 93 19 00 C0 99 B9 64
0020   FF FF FF FF FF FF C0 99 B9 32 00 00 55 00 00 DC
0030   00 6C 00 D6 00 00 00 A3 00 00 00 41
```

This is on the study guide for an networking exam that I am woefully unprepared for. The textbook says that the ARP packet is 20-24 bytes, which doesnt fit this data and its way too small to be an ethernet frame. However the series of hexadecimal FF's definately matches the broadcast output of ethernet. So confused. Help please.

Comment: Wikipedia article has description of ARP packet in this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol

Comment: Also, list of possible values for parameters: http://www.iana.org/assignments/arp-parameters/arp-parameters.xml

Comment: do you have a programming question?

Comment: this question may be better for http://serverfault.com/ if not for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That frame is 60 bytes long... the minimum is 64 bytes, and the drivers for most NICs will not send you the 4-byte CRC at the end of the frame... so that is a valid ethernet ARP frame; remember that ethernet frames are required to be a minimum of 64 bytes (measured from destination mac addr to the end of the CRC), and they get padded to that value if the upper protocols (i.e. ARP) don't use the minimum ethernet payload.  Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to decode the it.

Comment: You can use this web-based packet de-coder: http://sadjad.me/phd/